# Out of memory when running Keras model on GPU

Tags: python-3.x, keras, gpu, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run my model on cluster's GPU. However, every time I run my model I get OOM error. Previously, I tried running VGG on cluster's GPU and it ran fine. And VGG is a way deeper network than mine. My network is:

```
i1 = Input(shape=(1, 162, 5000))

c1 = Conv2D(100, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first')(i1)
#c1 = Conv2D(128*2, kernel_size=3,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first')(i1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)
c1 = Flatten()(c1)

i2 = Input(shape=(5000, ))
c2 = Dense(100, input_shape = (5000,), activation='relu')(i2)
c2 = Dropout(0.2)(c2)

c = concatenate([c1, c2])

x = Dense(100, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(c)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(5, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([i1, i2], [output])
```

And then in order to use multiprocessing I do the following:

```
parallel_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=2)

parallel_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer='adam',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


history = parallel_model.fit([image_train, positions_train], Ytest, batch_size=32,
          epochs=5,
          verbose=1,
          validation_split=0.2,
          shuffle=True)
```

My error is :

[image]

And total memory used is 70.37gb and reserved memory is 384g.

[image]

My questions:

1. Do you think it could be because it is using just one core?
2. How can I make it use all cores on one GPU node in Keras. I have 36 cores available? How can I incorporate it in my code.
3. Why is it that a deeper model like VGG runs fine but as soon as I try to run my model it runs into OOM error.

Model summary:

[image]

Help would be appreciated. I've been trying it for hours and haven't been able to solve this problem.

Comment: use model.summary() and see the number of trainable parameters, it is probably huge (hundreds of millions). That is the problem.

Comment: But how can I use all cores on GPU because right now it is using only one?

Comment: That is not the issue, GPUs don't have cores in the same sense as CPUs, your model is just too large to train on a GPU. Note that here I talk about GPU RAM, not CPU RAM.

Comment: I'm confused. Total memory of my GPU node is 384g but it uses only 70.37g. What does that mean?

Comment: First provide the results of model.summary(). The node has 384 GB of CPU RAM, the GPU has way less RAM, depending on model. The biggest GPU has 32 GB of RAM, which GPUs are you using?

Comment: I've added summary. And I'm running the model on my cluster. And it says it's Pny Tesla V100 - 16gb

Comment: So your model has 7997 Million parameters, just holding one instance of the models' parameters would require around 30 GB of GPU RAM. Do you see the problem now? For comparison, a typical VGG has around 133 Million parameters.

Comment: ok. That makes sense. I'll run it on CPU instead. But, when I run my code on CPU, it uses only 1 core but I would like it to use all 36 cores on my node. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You have to tell the cluster queueing system to assign you more than one core, TensorFlow will automatically use all available cores by default.